# Teradata space up issues

Tags: teradata

I have  a difficult time understanding a procedure which we use currently for increase the space and decreasing the space (space up and down) from a reserve database.Below is a part of the space down job:

```
LOCKING DBC.DiskSpace FOR ACCESS
 SELECT 
     (( (T1.MAXPERM) - (T1.MAXCURRENTPERM * T1.NUMAMPS))
              - (T2.SPACE_LEFT + T1.NUMAMPS)) (FORMAT 'Z(15)9') 
     INTO :var_SpaceAdj
  FROM Ctrl_Base.Space_Ctrl T2
       ,(
   SELECT DATABASENAME, SUM(MAXPERM), MAX(CURRENTPERM), COUNT(*)
    FROM DBC.DiskSpace
    WHERE DATABASENAME = :inP_Database
     GROUP BY 1) 
           AS T1 (DATABASENAME, MAXPERM, MAXCURRENTPERM, NUMAMPS)
   WHERE T1.DATABASENAME = T2.DATABASENAME
   AND (( (T1.MAXPERM) - (T1.MAXCURRENTPERM * T1.NUMAMPS))
      - (T2.SPACE_LEFT + T1.NUMAMPS)) >= 1000000
       ;
```

Acn anybody please help me understand what's this doing?
We have a Ctrl_Base.Space_Ctrl table where we specify the % increase while space up and space left entry

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((T1.MAXPERM) - (T1.MAXCURRENTPERM * T1.NUMAMPS))`

**T1.MAXPERM** - This is the total allocated space in the database

**T1.MAXCURRENTPERM** - This is the space from the AMP consuming the highest amount of space. Since data is distributed by the PI of table, uneven distribution of data can lead to a database reporting no space when the AMP consuming the highest space is unable to store any more data.

**(T1.MAXCURRENTPERM * T1.NUMAMPS)** - Calculates the *consumed* space for the database based on the AMP consuming the most space. Accounting for uneven data distribution in the database.

The derived table `T1` should be straightforward. It is simply aggregated the space information to the database level form the AMP, DatabaseName level in DBC.DiskSpace.

The second half of the `WHERE` clause is placing a condition that the difference in space for the database in T1 and the Space_Left column of the control table is greater than or equal to 1M bytes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks A lot Rob !! I couldn't understand one thing here:

Comment: Thanks A lot Rob !! I couldn't understand one thing here:
(T1.MAXCURRENTPERM * T1.NUMAMPS) - Calculates the consumed space for the database based on the AMP consuming the most space

How is this calculated??Suppose, DB_SPACE=100 GB,10 AMP SYSTEM, MAXCURRENtPERM=9GB then MAXCURRENTPERM*NUMAMPS=9*9=81GB.What's the significance of this here??

Comment: The database will report an out of space condition when one or more AMPs is unable to store data. In your example, as soon as the AMP consuming 9GB reaches 10GB, the next time that AMP is tasked with storing additional data the operation will fail. So reporting the space based on MAXCURRENTPERM yields the "effective" space consumption for the database.